# How to quit Xcode with confirmation dialog box using apple script

Tags: xcode, applescript

I'm trying to do a script to quit Xcode with currently building application. My current script only cover to quit Xcode but I'm unable to handle the confirmation dialog box that pop-ups on the Xcode. On the confirmation box, there are two button options: Cancel or Stop Tasks. I wanted to click on Stop Tasks button. Please help.

**Here's my current AppleScript so far:**

```
set apps to {"Simulator","Xcode"}
repeat with thisApp in apps
   tell application thisApp to quit
end repeat
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Xcode"
    click button "Stop Tasks" of sheet 1 of window 1
   end tell
end tell
```

This is my current applescript that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix my issue regarding terminating Xcode with confirmation dialog box prompt. Here's my the applescript I've come up:

```
try
    with timeout of 10 seconds
        quit application "Simulator"
        quit application "Xcode"
    end timeout
on error number e
    if e is -1712 then
        activate application "Xcode"
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Xcode"
                keystroke return
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end try
```